# Get in the habit

Tags: phrase-usage

I read a sentence:

> “Experience taught me how invaluable it is to reflect on and write down my decision-making criteria whenever I made a decision, so I **got in** the habit of doing that. ”

I barely interpreted 'get in' as 'develop or cultivate'.

I am not sure which meaning it takes from dictionary.

in Cambridge Dictionary: [get in](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/zhs/%E8%AF%8D%E5%85%B8/%E8%8B%B1%E8%AF%AD/get-in)

> to succeed in entering a place, especially by using force or a trick

In Oxford Dictionary [get in](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/get_in)

> 1.(of a train, aircraft, or other transport) arrive at its destination.
>   2(of a political party or candidate) be elected.

Comment: https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/in-the-habit-of-into-the-habit-of

Comment: {get} {in the habit} not {get in} {the habit}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The word *get* has a huge entry in the OED, with many meanings shown. Also, it's one of the most abused/over used words in the English language.

Perhaps your confusion here is the expression "in the habit of". It's somewhat idiomatic, and can be used with other verbs.

For example: She was in the habit of doing that.

So, using "get" before "in the habit" shows that the word "in" is not forming the phrasal verb "get in", but rather the word "in" belongs to the following expression.

I'd suggest the word *got* therefore means "came to be".  As to the relevant entry in the OED, might I suggest the following:

> (b) With prepositional phrase as complement: to reach or attain an
>    end aimed at, or a condition towards which progress has been made;
>    esp. to come to or come to be in a state or condition.

In your example this seems to be the case, as you could replace *got* with *"came to be"*

Comment: +1 for the advice on which meaning to select and for the information that it is not forming a phrasal verb. But -1 for "abused/over used".